# Gulp JS task never defined default

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp

I am working on a GuLP JS project here.

Inside my `gulpfile.js`:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

function compile() {
  return gulp
    .src("app/scss/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

// Watch for changes
function watch() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: "./app/",
    index: "./index.html",
  });

  gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", style);
  gulp.watch("./*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("./js/*.js").on("change", browserSync.reload);
}

exports.compile = compile;
exports.watch = watch;
```

When I run `gulp` on my terminal it returns a `Task never defined Default` error.

Any idea what am I missing here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export default (`exports.default = FUNCTION`) and point it to your desired default function (compile/watch) or you need to run your gulp like `gulp compile`/`gulp watch`.

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

function compile() {
  return gulp
    .src("app/scss/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

// Watch for changes
function watch() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: "./app/",
    index: "./index.html",
  });

  gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", style);
  gulp.watch("./*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("./js/*.js").on("change", browserSync.reload);
}

exports.compile = compile;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = compile;
```

Comment: Can you edit my code above and show me exactly where to put that? Sorry I am complete beginner.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I will add it in a moment.

Comment: Please do. I simply want to run both function on the run